# How does DVC store differences on the directory level into DVC cache?

Tags: version-control, dvc

Can someone explain how DVC stores differences on the directory level into DVC cache.

I understand that the DVC-files (.dvc) are metafiles to track data, models and reproduce pipeline stages. However, it is not clear for me how the process of creating branches, commiting them and switching back to a master file is exactly saved in differences.

Answer (score 4):

Short version:

1. `.dvc` file contains info (md5) about JSON file inside cache that describes current state of directory.
2. When directory gets updated, there is new md5 in `.dvc` file and new JSON file is created with updated state of directory.
3. In git, you store the  `.dvc` file, so that DVC know (basing on md5) where to look for information about directory.

Longer version:

Let me try to break particular steps of directory handling with DVC.

- Lets assume we have some data directory you want to add under DVC control:

```
data
├── 1
└── 2
```

- You are using `dvc add data` to make DVC track you directory. In result, DVC produces `data.dvc` file. As you noted this file contains metadata required to connect your git repository with your data storage. Inside this file (besides other things) you can see:

```
outs:
- md5: f437247ec66d73ba66b0ade0246fcb49.dir
 path: data
```

- The `md5` part is used to store information about directory in DVC cache (`.dvc/cache`):

```
(dvc3.7) ➜  repo$ tree .dvc/cache
.dvc/cache
├── 26
│   └── ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510
├── b0
│   └── 26324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1
└── f4
    └── 37247ec66d73ba66b0ade0246fcb49.dir
```

- If you will open the file with `.dir` suffix, you will see that it contains description of current `data` state:

```
(dvc3.7) ➜  repo$ cat .dvc/cache/f4/37247ec66d73ba66b0ade0246fcb49.dir 
[{"md5": "b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1", "relpath": "1"},
 {"md5": "26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510", "relpath": "2"}]
```

As you can see, particular files(`1` and `2`) are described by entries in this file

- When you change your directory:

```
(dvc3.7) ➜  repo$ echo 3 >> data/3 
(dvc3.7) ➜  repo$ dvc commit data.dvc
```

The content of `data.dvc` will be updated:

```
outs:
- md5: 12f4b7d54a32e58818e27fba28376fba.dir
  path: data
```

And there is new file inside the cache:

```
├── 12
│   └── f4b7d54a32e58818e27fba28376fba.dir
...

(dvc3.7) ➜  repo$ cat .dvc/cache/12/f4b7d54a32e58818e27fba28376fba.dir 
[{"md5": "b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1", "relpath": "1"},
 {"md5": "26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510", "relpath": "2"},
 {"md5": "6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03", "relpath": "3"}]
```

From perspecitve of git the only change is inside `data.dvc`. 
(Assuming you did `git commit` after adding `data` with `1` and `2` inside):

```
diff --git a/data.dvc b/data.dvc
index 098aec5..88d1a90 100644
--- a/data.dvc
+++ b/data.dvc
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
-md5: a427c5bf8680fbf8d1951806b28b82fe
+md5: 1b674d61c195eea7a6b14f176c020b9c
 outs:
-- md5: f437247ec66d73ba66b0ade0246fcb49.dir
+- md5: 12f4b7d54a32e58818e27fba28376fba.dir
   path: data
   cache: true
   metric: false
```

*NOTE: First md5 corresponds to md5 of this file, so it had to change with dir md5 change*

Comment: Also, check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365473/by-how-much-can-i-approx-reduce-disk-volume-by-using-dvc/60366262#60366262 - it's another explanation how DVC handles files.