# Downloading data from azure storage explorer using dvc

Tags: azure-blob-storage, dvc

I have an azure blob container with data which I have not uploaded myself. The data is not locally on my computer.
Is it possible to use dvc to download the data to my computer when I haven’t uploaded the data with dvc? Is it possible with dvc import-url?
I have tried using dvc pull, but can only get it to work if I already have the data locally on the computer and have used dvc add and dvc push .
And if I do it that way, then the folders on azure are not human-readable. Is it possible to upload them in a human-readable format?
If it is not possible is there then another way to download data automatically from azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll build up on [@Shcheklein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298182/shcheklein)'s great answer - specifically on the 'external dependencies' proposal - and focus on your last question, i.e. *"another way to download data automatically from Azure"*.

### Assumptions

Let's assume the following:

- We're using a DVC pipeline, specified in an existing `dvc.yaml` file. The first stage in the current pipeline is called `prepare`.
- Our data is stored on some Azure blob storage container, in a folder named `dataset/`. This folder follows a structure of sub-folders that we'd like to keep intact.
- The Azure blob storage container has been configured in our DVC environment as a DVC 'data remote', with name `myazure` (more info about DVC 'data remotes' [here](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remote))

### High-level idea

One possibility is to start the DVC pipeline by synchronizing a local `dataset/` folder with the `dataset/` folder on the remote container.

This can be achieved with a command-line tool called [`azcopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?WT.mc_id=thomasmaurer-blog-thmaure#download-azcopy), which is available for Windows, Linux and macOS.
As recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?WT.mc_id=thomasmaurer-blog-thmaure#download-azcopy), it is a good idea to add `azcopy` to your account or system path, so that you can call this application from any directory on your system.

The high-level idea is:

1. Add an initial `update_dataset` stage to the DVC pipeline that checks if changes have been made in the remote `dataset/` directory (i.e., file additions, modifications or removals).
   If changes are detected, the `update_datset` stage shall use the `azcopy sync [src] [dst]` command to apply the changes on the Azure blob storage container (the `[src]`) to the local `dataset/` folder (the `[dst]`)
2. Add a dependency between `update_dataset` and the subsequent DVC pipeline stage `prepare`, using a 'dummy' file. This file should be added to (a) the **outputs** of the `update_dataset` stage; and (b) the **dependencies** of the `prepare` stage.

### Implementation

This procedure has been tested on Windows 10.

1. Add a simple `update_dataset` stage to the DVC pipeline by running:

```
$ dvc stage add -n update_dataset -d remote://myazure/dataset/ -o .dataset_updated azcopy sync \"https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/dataset?[sas token]\" \"dataset/\" --delete-destination=\"true\"
```

Notice how we specify the 'dummy' file `.dataset_updated` as an output of the stage.

2. Edit the `dvc.yaml` file directly to modify the command of the `update_dataset` stage. After the modifications, the command shall (a) create the `.dataset_updated` file after the `azcopy` command - `touch .dataset_updated` - and (b) pass the current date and time to the `.dataset_updated` file to guarantee uniqueness between different update events - `echo %date%-%time% > .dataset_updated`.

```yaml
stages:
  update_dataset:
    cmd: azcopy sync "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/dataset?[sas token]" "dataset/" --delete-destination="true" && touch .dataset_updated && echo %date%-%time% > .dataset_updated # updated command
    deps:
    - remote://myazure/dataset/
    outs:
    - .dataset_updated
...
```

I recommend editing the `dvc.yaml` file directly to modify the command, as I wasn't able to come up with a complete `dvc add stage` command that took care of everything in one go.
This is due to the use of multiple commands chained by `&&`, special characters in the Azure connection string, and the `echo` expression that needs to be evaluated dynamically.

3. To make the `prepare` stage depend on the `.dataset_updated` file, edit the `dvc.yaml` file directly to add the new dependency, e.g.:

```yaml
stages:
  prepare:
    cmd: <some command>
    deps:
    - .dataset_updated # add new dependency here
    - ... # all other dependencies
...
```

4. Finally, you can test different scenarios on your remote side - e.g., adding, modifying or deleting files - and check what happens when you run the DVC pipeline up till the `prepare` stage:

```
$ dvc repro prepare
```

### Notes

- The solution presented above is very similar to the example given in DVC's [external dependencies documentation](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/data-management/importing-external-data#examples).
  Instead of the `az copy` command, it uses `azcopy sync`.
  The advantage of `azcopy sync` is that it only applies the differences between your local and remote folders, instead of 'blindly' downloading everything from the remote side when differences are detected.
- This example relies on a full connection string with an SAS token, but you can probably do without it if you configure `azcopy` with your credentials or fetch the appropriate values from environment variables
- When defining the DVC pipeline stage, I've intentionally left out an output dependency with the local `dataset/` folder - i.e. the `-o dataset` part - as it was causing the `azcopy` command to fail. I think this is because DVC automatically clears the folders specified as output dependencies when you reproduce a stage.
- When defining the `azcopy` command, I've included the `--delete-destination="true"` option. This allows synchronization of deleted files, i.e. files are deleted on your local `dataset` folder if deleted on the Azure container.

Answer (score 1):

Please, bear with me, since you have a lot of questions. Answer needs a bit structure and background to be useful. Or skip to the very end to find some new ways of doing `Is it possible to upload them in a human-readable format?` :). Anyways, please let me know if that solves your problem, and in general would be great to have a better description of what you are trying to accomplish at the end (high level description).

---

You are right that by default DVC structures its remote in a content-addressable way (which makes it non human-readable). There are pros and cons to this. It's easy to deduplicate data, it's easy to enforce immutability and make sure that no one can touch it directly and remove something, directory names in projects make it connected to actual project and their meaning, etc.

Some materials on this: [Versioning Data and Models](https://dvc.org/doc/use-cases/versioning-data-and-models), my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365473/by-how-much-can-i-approx-reduce-disk-volume-by-using-dvc/60366262#60366262) of on how DVC structures its data, upcoming [Data Management](https://github.com/iterative/dvc.org/pull/4042/files) User Guide section (WIP still).

Saying that, it's clear there are downsides to this approach, especially when it comes to managing a lot of objects in the cloud (e.g. millions of images, etc). To name a few concerns that I see a lot as a pattern:

- Data has been created (and being updated) by someone else. There is some ETL, third party tool, etc. We need to keep that format.
- Third party tool expect to have data in "human" readable way. It doesn't integrate with DVC to being able to access it indirectly via Git. (one of the examples - Label Studio need direct links to S3).
- It's not practical to move all of data into DVC, it doesn't make sense to instantiate all the files at once as one directory. Users need slices, usually based on some annotations (metadata), etc.

So, DVC has multiple features to deal with data in its own original layout:

- [`dvc import-url`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/import-url) - it'll download objects, it'll cache them, and will by default push (`dvc push`) to remote to again save them to guarantee reproducibility (this can be changed). This command creates a special file `.dvc` that is being used to detect changes in the cloud to see if DVC needs to download something again. It should cover the case for "to download data automatically from azure".
- [`dvc get-url`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/get-url) - this more or less `wget` or `rclone` or `aws s3 cp`, etc with multi cloud support. It just downloads objects.

**A bit advanced thing (if you DVC pipelines):**

- Similar to `import-url` but for DVC pipelines - [external dependencies](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/data-management/importing-external-data)

**The the third (new) option.** It's in beta phase, it's called "cloud versioning" and essentially it tries to keep the storage human readable while still benefit from using `.dvc` files in Git if you need them to reference an exact version of the data.

[Cloud Versioning with DVC](https://github.com/iterative/dvc.org/pull/4165/files#diff-2a486fe891f01970fcf67c031b11d1b2e086407954bfe35d705c9b2d1036315b) (it's WPI when I write this, if PR is merged it means you can find it in the [docs](https://dvc.org/doc)

The document summarizes well the approach:

> DVC supports the use of cloud object versioning for cases where users prefer to retain their original filenames and directory hierarchy in remote storage, in exchange for losing the de-duplication and performance benefits of content-addressable storage. When cloud versioning is enabled, DVC will store files in the remote according to their original directory location and
> filenames. Different versions of a file will then be stored as separate versions of the corresponding object in cloud storage.