# How to add/update data with dvc workflow?

Tags: git, machine-learning, dvc

I want to know , when we set up [DVC](https://dvc.org), can I simply, add my entire directory as such, `dvc add dataset` and my workflow would be to update the entire dataset folder for next iteration. The contents of this folder should be cached. And if I ever wanna go back to previous version of data, I should be able to do a `dvc checkout`? Or is it better to add each file to DVC individually?

```
— .dvc
  - config
— dataset
  - fileone.cvs
- train.py
- requirements.txt
```

I have tracked individual files so far, but would be easier to track entire folder in the event I have 100s of files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the whole directory can be added at once and this is the recommended way to handle directories in DVC. Having 100s of `.dvc` files is discouraged and not what DVC is optimized for.

Here is an [example](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/add#example-directory) in the documentation. Pretty much, you can do:

```bash
dvc add dataset
```

No matter how many files are inside the `dataset` directory, DVC will create a single `dataset.dvc` file that will handle the whole directory. Files will be cached (one time per unique file per dataset).

To update it later, you could run `dvc add` or `dvc commit`. To get to the previous version, you will be able to do use the same mechanics as described [here](https://dvc.org/doc/start/data-management/data-versioning#switching-between-versions).

Here is the brief summary of [some technical details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365473/by-how-much-can-i-approx-reduce-disk-volume-by-using-dvc/60366262#60366262) that I recommend to read if you'd like to understand the implications better.

If there a lot of files inside the directory, please also read [Large Dataset Optimization](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/data-management/large-dataset-optimization).